# How to change matrix rows or columns names by a list of existing names to new?

Tags: r, database, matrix, names

I have a matrix that it's rows and columns named by some ID number.
I have another database which contains two columns - one of IDs and one of some names.

I need to change the name of the columns and rows in the matrix to its names according to what I have in the other database.

List of IDs and Names:

```
#   ID  NAME  
#    1   chocolate   
#    2   hamburger   
#    3   nudels
#    4   rice  
#    5   sushi 
#    6   ice cream   
#    7   chicken
```

my matrix:

```
#headline:  1   3   6  7
#           x   x   x  x
#           x   x   x  x
#           x   x   x  x
#           x   x   x  x
```

what I want:

```
#headline:  chocolate   nudels   ice cream  chicken
#           x           x        x          x
#           x           x        x          x
#           x           x        x          x
#           x           x        x          x
```

and the same principle with the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following matrix

```
mat <- matrix(1:16, 4)
set.seed(1)
colnames(mat) <- sample(9, 4, FALSE)
mat
#     3 9  5  6
#[1,] 1 5  9 13
#[2,] 2 6 10 14
#[3,] 3 7 11 15
#[4,] 4 8 12 16
```

and this lookup table

```
(lookup <- data.frame(ID = 1:10,
                      NAME = LETTERS[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
#    ID NAME
#1    1    A
#2    2    B
#3    3    C
#4    4    D
#5    5    E
#6    6    F
#7    7    G
#8    8    H
#9    9    I
#10  10    J
```

we can use `match(colnames(mat), lookup$ID)` to find the positions of the old column names and use the this vector to subset column `NAME` from the lookup table

```
colnames(mat) <- lookup$NAME[match(colnames(mat), lookup$ID)]
mat
#     C I  E  F
#[1,] 1 5  9 13
#[2,] 2 6 10 14
#[3,] 3 7 11 15
#[4,] 4 8 12 16
```

---

If we need to change both row names and column names *to be the same* we can use `` `dimnames<-` `` as follows

```
dimnames(mat) <- rep(list(lookup$NAME[match(colnames(mat), lookup$ID)]), 2)
```

But I am not sure from the question if this is what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very similar answer to Markus' answer.

I am just including the rownames update too (as requested) and taking advantage of  names of vectors to build a lookup vector.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:7,
  NAME = c('chocolate', 'hamburger', 'nudels', 'rice', 'sushi', 'ice cream', 'chicken'))

# Create a lookup vector from the IDs/Names dataframe
lookup <- df$NAME
names(lookup) <- df$ID

# Dummy matrix for illustration purposes
mat <- matrix(1:16, 4)
set.seed(1)
colnames(mat) <- sample(7, 4, FALSE)
rownames(mat) <- sample(7, 4, FALSE)
mat
#>   2 3  6  4
#> 2 1 5  9 13
#> 6 2 6 10 14
#> 5 3 7 11 15
#> 3 4 8 12 16

# Update colnames and rownames according to the lookup.
colnames(mat) <- lookup[colnames(mat)]
rownames(mat) <- lookup[rownames(mat)]
mat
#>           hamburger nudels ice cream rice
#> hamburger         1      5         9   13
#> ice cream         2      6        10   14
#> sushi             3      7        11   15
#> nudels            4      8        12   16
```

Comment: Thank you, but this will work only if my IDs are arranged 1,2,3,4...etc, I mean, the numbers in a row, Right?
Because I don't see the use of "names(lookup)" anywhere to identify the location of the ID in the vector if not by it's numeric location.

Comment: @DanBoguslavsky: why not try it? (hint: it should work).

Answer (score 0):

I found using recode from `dplyr` is a good alternative

```
mat = matrix(1:16, 4)
set.seed(1)
colnames(mat)= sample(9, 4, FALSE)
mat
#      9 4  7  1
# [1,] 1 5  9 13
# [2,] 2 6 10 14
# [3,] 3 7 11 15
# [4,] 4 8 12 16
lookup = data.frame(ID = 1:10,
                     NAME = LETTERS[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
lookup.list=split(lookup$NAME,lookup$ID) # convert lookup table to a list
colnames(mat)=recode(colnames(mat),
                     !!!lookup.list) #Use a named character vector for unquote splicing with !!!

#     I D  G  A
# [1,] 1 5  9 13
# [2,] 2 6 10 14
# [3,] 3 7 11 15
# [4,] 4 8 12 16
```